# Событие Ondrag android

Tags: android, java

У меня есть ListView. когда я зажимаю пальцем какой-то элемент появляется фрагмент после перетаскивания на который удаляется элемент. Но когда я перетаскиваю фрагмент удаление не исчезает, как отследить когда пользователь убрал палец и перестал тянуть, чтоб можно было убрать тот фрагмент?

```
package com.msdlab.tasks.app.ui.fragment;

import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.DragEvent;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;

import com.msdlab.tasks.app.R;

public class RemoveBarFragment extends BarFragment {

    private final static String LOG_TAG = "BarFragment/RemoveBarFragment";
    private void init(){
        thisView.findViewById(R.id.removeImageButton).setOnDragListener(new View.OnDragListener() {
            @Override
            public boolean onDrag(View v, DragEvent event) {
                Log.d("dragEvent", "event : " + event.getAction());
                switch (event.getAction()) {
                    case DragEvent.ACTION_DROP:
                        sendCommand(FactoryCommandFragment.getInstance().getCommand("dragged,remove"));
                    default:
                }

                return true;
            }
        });
        executeCommand(FactoryCommandFragment.getInstance().getTopCommand("top,default"));
        redraw();
    }

    public void redraw(){
    }

    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        thisView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_remove_bar, container, false);
        init();
        return thisView;

    }

    public void executeCommand(Command command) {
        if (thisView == null) {
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Command suspended");
            SuspendedCommand suspended = new SuspendedCommand();
            suspended.execute(command);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "Command executed");
            return;
        }
        for (int i = 0; i < command.getCount(); i++) {
            String commandString = command.getCommand(i);
            Log.d(LOG_TAG, "command - " + commandString);
            String delim = "[,]";
            String[] tokens = commandString.split(delim);
            if (tokens.length == 0) {
                throw new IllegalArgumentException("build commandString[" + i + "] is empty");
            }

            if (tokens[0].equalsIgnoreCase("redraw")) {
                if (tokens.length == 1) {
                    redraw();
                }

            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Добавьте обработку события
    case DragEvent.ACTION_DRAG_ENDED: /*юзер перестал тянуть*/ break;

Comment: это не помогло. проблема была решена. Вообщем решили отказаться от верхнего фрагмента, просто меняли динамически лэйаут на верхнем баре. Проблема была в том, что когда юзер зажимает элемент List View, пока он не отпустит OnDragListener не зарегестрируется на вьюху удаления по непонятным причинам. Это случилось после апдейта на андроид 19.1. Поэтому решили обойти это дело